# Android: Aggregating key value pairs in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to aggregate key value pairs in the same shared preferences from different activities?

For example, if I have a shared preference named "SP" and it has a key "SP_A" that I have stored it through activity A. This key has some value. How can I aggregate another key "SP_B" with some value, through activity B in the same shared preference "SP", such that in activity C, I can retrieve key values corresponding to "SP_A" and "SP_B" under the same shared preference "SP"?

And if this question is being downvoted, I would encourage to please write in comment your reason to downvote it. If some question is a bad question liable to be downvoted, people should know the reason why it is bad so that they improve their question asking skills and the quality of questions on this forum gradually improves. Anonymous downvoting and running away will not help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a `SharedPreference` using something like:

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You can access it and write to it from anywhere in your app in the same way you created it. In fact, its just an xml file within your app's local storage.

Comment: Yeah I think its a common misconception that that if a Shared Preference was created from Activity A it can only be read from Activity A. You can read it from anywhere in your application. Its the shared preference name that tells you what content you are accessing, the context used to access it is irrelevant.

Comment: @w.donahue exactly...another MAJOR misconception: its OK to scatter static methods and variables throughout the app